# Where can I find a QR (quick response) Code component/API for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, components, qr-code

I am looking for a **3rd party solution to integrate a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) reader** in Windows Mobile Applications (.NET Compact Framework). The component should **integrate Reader (camera) and Decoder (algorithm)**.

I tried out the [QuickMark](http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/index.asp) reader, which can be called outside the application and communicates using Windows Messages. It works quiet well, but doesn't give me every option I need (e.g. it has to be installed etc.).

Are there other good solutions which I may have missed? Anything Open Source? Tested on different devices?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx) is an open source C# port of the Java QR Code [library](http://qrcode.sourceforge.jp/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one: [QRCode .NET Compact Framework Package](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/E-Commerce/QRCode-NET-Compact-Framework-Package--30802.html)  ?

Comment: What I need is a QR code *Reader*. On first look this library can only generate codes on mobile devices. What I'm looking for should read codes using the camera and return a string to my app.